# How to display a google map in flask/django?

Tags: python

There's not much to be said about it except for the absence of any form of documentation having the least possible understandable way of doing it. Google's documentation only includes JS snippets that are good enough if I know how to use them in flask, django, or whatever python web framework.

Comment: ...I don't understand the confusion. Have you looked at Google's documentation for embedding maps? What part of it is unclear? How are Django and Flask relevant? (And which one are you using? They are entirely different products.)

Comment: The confusion is because I don't know how the embedding is done. It's not a problem with google's documentation, it's me not knowing how to do it in any python web framework. So far I tried with flask, all attempts are guesswork leading nowhere past a blank page. Most of the confusion is coming from not knowing what exactly is that I need to learn/look for/google to get it over with.

Comment: Do you have some kind of templating system set up? Somewhere where you can put HTML, CSS, etc?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean by templating system, then yeah I create a new flask / django project template in pycharm which generates the necessary files, and I'm familiar with the pretty basic stuff. I've previously written simple one-page interfaces, nothing complicated.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing. [Django has its own templating system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/), and [Flask uses Jinja2](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/templates/). Both let you build HTML interfaces, and in an interface like that you can just apply what Google tells you.

Comment: Just an update, I was able to show display a map in flask just now based on the answer posted earlier, and yes, I'm familiar with jinja2 syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Flask and Django you make HTML pages in the end, and from Flask you can just return some HTML with the parameters you need.

The Google maps embed API uses an iframe, so you can display a map on your page like this:

```html
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  style="border:0"
  loading="lazy"
  allowfullscreen
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA">
</iframe>
```

"You can set the Maps Embed API URL as the src attribute of an iframe" says the doc with that in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started

In your Flask or Django view thing, you can then have for example the geocoordinates of the map place you want, gmaps has had a nice API for ages.

For adding markers, heatmaps etc. from code, the Maps client side JS api works, so you'd do that on the client but can get data for the front JS code from your Python backend. I have a simple old gmaps app that is browser side JS only, reads the marker data from a JSON, in https://github.com/playsign/insideoulu/blob/master/map.js

Comment: Probably it does but do you have an idea whether it supports interaction: heatmaps, markers, ...? I mean it's not part of the static api right?

Comment: Yes with that API you can add heatmaps, markers, whatever. It's a part of the client side API but you can feed it with data from the back.

Comment: The client side JS API supports creating markers etc. with code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension in **flask**  it only requires

```
Jinja
Flask
A google api key
```

And to use in your project use thy dependency manager and pip-install it like this

```
pip install flask-googlemaps
```

For how-to-use check out their documentation [here](https://github.com/flask-extensions/Flask-GoogleMaps) it's pretty straightforward.